# SQL GUID turns to Uppercase in tojson query

Tags: javascript, sql-server, guid

SQL Server return all SQL_GUID datatypes in uppercase. But I need them in lowercase by default.

I have to return data query as Json format to use in angular front-end and  uppercase Guid must compare with same Guid in lowercase but the result of this comparison its false.

Is there a way for SQL Server to return Guids in lowecase without use of built-in SQL lower function ?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but perhaps consider storing your UUIDs as binary in your SQL Server database.  In addition to saving some storage space, you could also just compare that binary directly against binary in the front end.

Comment: GUIDs are their own data type in SQL Server, `uniqueidentifier`, and they will always have uppercase letters, if you try `SELECT CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,'f6af441f-bea8-4760-86ab-91464e55b091')` it will be in upper case. You will have to treat the value as a `varchar` and use `lower` if you want lowercase letters. I don't, suggest *storing* the values as a `varchar`; just pass the lowercase value when dealing with your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to use `LOWER`?

Comment: My two centavos on this - you're talking about format, not content... and that's not something the database should be concerned about. If it's a GUID, then send it back as a GUID, and let the js figure out what it needs to do with it to make the comparison. If it was a Date, we wouldn't be having this discussion... we'd be letting SQL Server send back a date and then using Moment, or a js Date to "format" it to do the comparison, not SQL Server.... so why should a GUID/UUID be any different?

Comment: @MartinSmith  all of my logic are in sp's and functions and finally results are returns as JSON format and i deliver it to angular front-end , if i want to use lower i have to make a lot of changes , be side i think it's not a clean cod if i write lower before all GUIDs fields in final select querys also in angular .

Answer (score 3):

The **GUID** is basically a 16-byte binary value. There are no items like upper case or lower case in binary values (or integers).You can use ToUpper or ToLower to make them look the way you want.

to upper case in SQL Server

```
SELECT UPPER ('8B94A1DA-1956-4D2E-A3A3-30CC52F589F9');
```

to lower case in SQL Server

```
SELECT LOWER ('8B94A1DA-1956-4D2E-A3A3-30CC52F589F9');
```

to upper case in angular

```
'8B94A1DA-1956-4D2E-A3A3-30CC52F589F9'.toUpperCase( );
```

to lower case in angular

```
'8B94A1DA-1956-4D2E-A3A3-30CC52F589F9'.toLowerCase( );
```

Comment: Dont think either SQL Server, or JavaScript have ToUpper / ToLower functions or methods

Comment: @RezaJenabi toUpperCase and toLowerCase are Javascript functions. Angular is a Javascript library, but it's not necessary in order to use the functions you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: If you would like to store GUIDs formatted as lowercase string in your SQL DB table, you can add a computed column, or write a view that returns the GUID as lower. This sample implicitly converts the GUID to VARCHAR and formats in lowercase.

```
declare @t table(
    u uniqueidentifier, 
    GuidAsLower as lower(u)
)
insert @t values(newid())
select * from @t
```

Returns

```
u:F0BA5160-F5DE-779D-B336-2012B09DDB7F  
GuidAsLower:f0ba5160-f5de-779d-b336-2012b09ddb7f
```